# ANTLR4 how should (a|b)+ behave

Tags: antlr4

I have a parser grammar like:
c:(a|b)+;

a is like:
name EQ INT

b is like:
name EQ ALPHA

when I test using a sequence that looks like "b b a", I get an error indicating a failure parsing the "a"  as the parser was expecting ALPHA - as if it was expecting b.

I thought (a|b)+ would find any chain of arbitrarily ordered a's and b's - similar to a [ab]+ for character classes. But this appears to be expecting whichever option is found initially to be repeated without the other option mingled in.

Am I understanding the meaning of (a|b)+ wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct - that is how it does work.

The problem here is likely that the `a` and `b` rules are behaving exactly as ANTLR (but not you) intend. Cannot say without seeing a grammar that reproduces the error.

Note, unit tests give only limited visibility into problems of this type.  To debug, first dump the token stream to ensure that the lexer rules are correct: intended sequence of token type and text content.

If correct, then examine the parser rule operation by dumping the parse-tree. This can be done using `Parser#toStringTree()` or the `grun` tool, for example. Or, if you are using an IDE, checkout their associated ANTLR plugins.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It helps me know I need to look for the cause of the problem elsewhere in the grammar.  I used grun to dump the token stream as you suggested. I understand why I'm getting the result - its the order of two lexer rules that are giving the same length match. I can't reverse them bc it will break a different section.  I need to rethink the role of lexer and parser in what I am doing.